# Trying to embed a stream from a Honeywell IP security camera

Tags: video, video-streaming, ip-camera

I have a project where a client has recently installed a Honeywell HDZ302LIK security camera at their camp and they want to embed the camera feed on their homepage.

Thats all fine and dandy, but I can't for the life of me find out how to get the raw feed outside their remote access software.

I'm offsite and helping out a friend with this. My current solution is opening a web browser (IE is the only thing i can get it working in) and point x split at it and streaming out from that.

Here is the URL https://camptowanda.hennvr-ddns.com/ It has a certificate error as well...

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That definitely sounds promising. I've not tried/heard of sniffers. Suggestions?

Comment: Yeah I think I could figure it out from there.

Answer (score 1):

A quick test showed that the camera supports rtsp. You can try to put the rtssp URL in a video tag but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

This could help you, it explains how to cast rtsp to youtube live which you should be able embed on a website.

http://www.georgetimmermans.com/blog/streaming-rtsp-to-youtube-live

another option https://idle.run/ip-camera-stream

Answer (score 1):

You could use the RTSP URL, needs some embedding but this works:

rtsp://Username:Password@[IP Address]:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0

IB